# GitHub Actions workflow do not respond to push event in other workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have created a workflow that automatically merges branch A into branch B when branch A is pushed and a workflow that runs when branch B is pushed. However, the workflow does not run when branch B is pushed. Is this a GitHub specification? If so, I would like to know if there is documentation or an issue that clearly states this.

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "A" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
          
      - name: Merge branch B
        run: |
          git fetch
          git checkout B
          git merge A
          git push origin B
```

```yaml
name: CI-2

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "B" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
          
      - name: Test
        run: echo Hello
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [official documentation (triggering a workflow from a workflow)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)
, this issue occurs because:

> When you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN` **will not create a new workflow run**. This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs. For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN`, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

To make it work:

> If you do want to trigger a workflow from within a workflow run, you can use a **personal access token** instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN` to trigger events that require a token. You'll need to create a personal access token and store it as a secret. To minimize your GitHub Actions usage costs, ensure that you don't create recursive or unintended workflow runs. For more information about creating a personal access token, see "[Creating a personal access token.](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)" For more information about storing a personal access token as a secret, see "[Creating and storing encrypted secrets.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)"

If you're not familiar with the `GITHUB_TOKEN` concept and want to get more context about its usage, I suggest to check [this section from the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

Comment: Thank you very much And I'm sorry I missed it when it's right there in the official docs...